# Adding a filter with custom function to the menu / navigation

Tags: functions, menus

I'm going to get crazy with the problem:

I want to add a specific css class to the menu items, depending on a custom taxonomy. This is my code so far.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'auto_custom_type_class', 10, 2 );
function auto_custom_type_class($classes, $item) {

if($item->object == "marke") {
   if( has_term( "laden-1", "laden", $item->ID ) ) {
        $classes []= "laden-1";
   }
}
return $classes;
}
```

First I check, if the post type is "marke"
After that I check, if the "marke" has the characteristics "laden-1" at the taxonomy "laden".

After about three hours I think, that there is a problem with the function "has_term", It seems that this function is not called correctly.

Does anybody has a suggestion?

Many many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're settings up your menus but this is probably the most reliable method.

```
function auto_custom_type_class( $classes, $item ) {
    $type = get_post_type( $item->object_id );
    if( $type == "marke" && has_term( "laden-1", "laden", $item->object_id ) ) {
        $classes []= "laden-1";
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'auto_custom_type_class', 10, 2 );
```

The problem with your code is that `$item->ID` refers the to the navigational items ID instead of the actual post ID which is found at `$item->object_id`. Using the ID to get the post type is probably more reliable than checking `$item->object` though you may be able to use that method.

Comment: Perfectly! Thanks 1000 times! I newer thought about that!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... try this:

```
// Adding menu classes based on single post taxonomy terms
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
        $post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID());
        if( is_single() && $post_type == 'marke' && has_term( 'laden-1', 'laden' ){
                $classes[] = 'laden-1';
        }
        return $classes;
}
```